# O que significa uma resposta atravessada!

Tags: português-brasileiro

Ou pessoal,

O que significa **uma resposta atravessada**? Quer dizer uma **resposta forte**?

> Tobi recusou a proposta e ainda deu uma resposta atravessada ao amigo!

Comment: Conheço a expresao "olhar atravessado".

Answer (score 3):

Não. Significa uma resposta dada com irritação, em geral grosseira.

Como o Aulete [coloca](https://www.aulete.com.br/atravessado), um dos significados de "atravessado" é

> 7. Muito aborrecido; ENCOLERIZADO; IRRITADO: *O chefe chegou atravessado, melhor nem chegar perto.* [ Antôn.: bem-humorado, calmo. ]

Comment: Pela minha experiência, também poder ser distorcido, fora, esquisito, que não deveria ser ou esquivador como «ontem ele disse “almoçaremos junto no Sábado”, hoje já deu uma resposta atravessada, disse “Viajarei no sábado, Água de Lindóia!”» e «Perguntei-lhe sua opinião do racismo, deu-nos uma resposta atravessada: “É uma coisa. Né?”». Pelo menos é assim que a minha família de muito familiar. +1

Comment: @Schilive Interessante, não conhecia esse uso, mas parece natural.

Comment: Que curioso... para mim aborrecido é ou entediado ou desagradado, mas não colérico ou irritado.

Comment: @ANevesthinksSEisevil Para mim também. Penso que os termos em maiúsculas são os significados principais, não exatamente equivalentes entre si (por isso separados por ponto e vírgula) e nem com o primeiro ("muito aborrecido").

Answer (score 1):

Seria uma resposta que pode estar relacionada com sarcasmo, com respostas agressivas ou cáusticas. Muito possivelmente por não gostar da pergunta que lhe é feita ou do tom utilizado, a pergunta atravessada pode surgir e ser entendida mais rispidamente.

Answer (score 0):

Uma resposta rude, grosseira, malvada

Answer (score 0):

Uma resposta grossa e com raiva

Answer (score 0):

no nordeste, "resposta atravessada", significa que alguem respondeu sem ter sido o alvo da pergunta, o "atravessado" seria alguem intrometido.